# In AngularJS, is it possible to pass the source element as a parameter in its ng-class attribute?

Tags: angularjs, parameter-passing, ng-class

Please, consider the following example for understanding my question:

```
<button ng-class="$scope.controllerMethod($thisButton)" />
```

In my controllerMethod, I want to get a reference of the button who called ng-class. Is it possible?

(Something like passing $event.target in the ng-click button, so I can read the caller from the controller).

Any helps? Thanks!!

Comment: No. You should create your directive for that.

Comment: What do you really want to do?  I mean why do you want to know this information?  I suspect there is a better/easier/Angular way to do what you want, but I can't figure out what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to highlight a button in my menu bar when user clicks it, and get highlight out of the other buttons dynamically. What would be an alternative to this? Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you mean by "get highlight out of the other buttons dynamically"? I'm not sure what you mean by this. If you can provide an example of this somewhere that would also be super useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hard coding each of your button in your menu, you won't need `ng-class`. Simply `ng-click=doSomething('$event')`, then the rest is just like your normal Javascript, do whatever you want with `$event.target`.

If you want do it the angular way, each button needs to have a corresponding model in the controller.

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat='btn in buttons'>
   <button ng-class='{"highlight":btn.clicked}' ng-click='doSomething(btn)'></button>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.buttons = [{text:'button1'},{text:'button2'}];

$scope.doSomething = function(btn){
   btn.clicked = true;
}
```

In this example, ng-class will watch each button's `clicked` property, if it's true, then add `highlight` class onto this button.